# How can I assign roles with Discord.py client?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating this bot to assign and remove roles based on Xp, but first I'm trying to make it assign roles.

Code because I'm having a hard time trying to post my fist code lol:

[image]

Comment: Is this kind of information not covered in the documentation?

Comment: I have never used Discord.py before and I barely know Python, but I found [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Member.add_roles) after a quick search of the documentation. Also, please do not post pictures of your code. It is much easier for people to help you if you copy and paste the code and format it correctly instead.

Answer (score 1):

by using `client.add_roles()` you are trying to give your client(bot) the role, instead you would want to give the role to a member, probably the author of the message.
Also, the client is not supposed to be inside the function, rather put it at the top of your code somewhere.

Comment: That's my second attempt, by the way, I tried using "user.add_roles()"  but then the user has no permission to give ADM role :(

Answer (score 0):

This should give the author the role `Adm`, make sure the bot itself has a role with the permission to `manage roles` in the guild.

```py
rom discord.utils import get

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Adm')
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: I tried that but even allowing Administrator role for my bot on Discord api or even giving Adm role on my server still "Missing Permissions :/ what am I doing wrong?

Comment: give the bot itself a role with `manage roles` permission as mentioned above. The bot can only give roles under it in the guild **order is important**